ASP.NET Core Web API with .NET Maui
I'm using ASP.NET Core Web API with two login parts one for normal and one for a database login works great and the database login works great but I can't store the username in existing JWT, so I can use in other stored procedures with the username that I use to login in database login?
I have already tried to add a new claim when I execute the stored procedure but it didn't also tried to store in header it didn't work.
Should I consider using two JWT or should I just try to update the existing one?

Based on your scenario, updating the existing JWT to include additional claims (such as the database username) is generally the simplest and most efficient approach. It allows you to keep a single token while still having access to all necessary information. However, without having look at  your code it's hard to offer you any exact solution.

i have listed the code now

When you are saying, it didn't work, what did you mean? It diddn't updated the claims or token has not been generated or got any error? What are you struggling with?

if i want to update the claim it wont be updated like it is going null all time also i dont want to reset it i just want to update it like i don't want to generate a new key

If you want to update an existing JWT token without generating a new one, the JWT standard does not support modifying a token after it is issued because it would invalidate the signature. However, if you want to keep the existing claims and just update or add new ones without invalidating the token, you need to issue a new token with the updated claims.

but can i generate like two JWT tokens one for log in one for database is that okay or may i have issues

It would certainly introduces some complexity in managing and validating these tokens for example, keeping both tokens in sync and ensuring they are invalidated correctly can be challenging. However, you can have two tokens but not sure what additional issue it may cause.

No problem, for future reference to other, I am adding this  as answer, I hope that would help.


Should I consider using two JWT or should I just try to update the
existing one?

If you want to update an existing JWT token without generating a new one, the JWT standard does not support modifying a token after it is issued because it would invalidate the signature. However, if you want to keep the existing claims and just update or add new ones without invalidating the token, you need to issue a new token with the updated claims.

Can i generate like two JWT tokens one for log in one for database is
that okay or may i have issues

It would certainly introduces some complexity in managing and validating these tokens for example, keeping both tokens in sync and ensuring they are invalidated correctly can be challenging. However, you can have two tokens but not sure what additional issue it may cause.
Anyway, while it’s technically feasible to issue two separate JWT tokens, ensure that your application handles them appropriately. If the complexity becomes unmanageable, consider revisiting the single token approach with updated claims.
Note: Please refer this official document for additional information and clarity.
